# Gird sorting and filter doesn't work on some columns in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

Sorting and filter are not working on some columns in @html.grid. In this grid, I am getting columns UserName, Email and site from another table by their Id's.
Here is the code

```
     @Html.Grid(Model).Named("UserGrid").Columns(x =>
{
    x.Add(y => y.UserID);
    x.Add().Titled("User Name").Sortable(true).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(100).RenderValueAs(y=>String.Join(",", y.UserList.Select(e=>e.UserName).ToArray()));
    x.Add().Titled("Email").Sortable(true).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(100).RenderValueAs(y=>String.Join(",", y.UserList.Select(e=>e.Email).ToArray()));
    x.Add().Titled("Site").Sortable(true).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(100).RenderValueAs(y=>String.Join(",", y.SiteList.Select(e=>e.Location).ToArray()));
    x.Add(y => y.Comments);
    x.Add(y => y.AdditionalComments);
    x.Add().Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(20)
        .RenderValueAs(y => Html.ActionLink(" Edit", "Edit", new { id = y.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary fa fa-chevron-circle-down" }));
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable(true)
```

Here is the output I am getting:- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRpSt.jpg)

In this pic UserId, Comments and additional comments are working, rest of columns are not working which I am getting from another table. Please advise where I am wrong.

Comment: Heys Guys, please can anybody help me out for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your rendering with the render value

```
  .RenderValueAs(y => Html.ActionLink(" Edit", "Edit", new { id = y.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary fa fa-chevron-circle-down" }));
```

you need to run like this:

```
x.Add(m=>m.Id).Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .SetWidth(20)
        .RenderValueAs(y => Html.ActionLink(" Edit", "Edit", new { id = y.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary fa fa-chevron-circle-down" }));
```

your filter will be run with ordering and filtering.